# How to add a JS Component via XML?

Tags: magento2, javascript, xml, requirejs

How could I add a new **JS Component**, using required and following the Magento's pattern via an XML which I can determine a unique page (e.g. using a `checkout_index_index.xml`)

I don't want to create a PHTML just to add load a JS Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `checkout_index_index.xml` in your module or theme, then add it via an **uiComponent**, as you can see in this example below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="vendor-module-popup" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                                                                            Vendor_Module/js/popup-message
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then in my JS extend the component.

```
define(
    ['jQuery', 'ko', 'uiComponent', 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    function ($, ko, Component, quote, shipping) {
        'use strict';
        let self;
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/notice'
            },
            showAlert: ko.observable(false),
            initialize: function () {
                self = this;
                this._super();
                )
            }
        })
    }
);
```